# How to disable StyleCop Plus rule SP2001 "Only tab characters are allowed to be used for indentation"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, stylecop, stylecop-plus

I have added a nuget package `StyleCopPlus.MSBuild` https://www.nuget.org/packages/StyleCopPlus.MSBuild/4.7.49.5

which comes with `Settings.StyleCop` that I can copy to solution folder and modify,
but I'm getting warning `SP2001 "Only tab characters are allowed to be used for indentation"` but I can't find a rule to disable it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [#pragma warning disable & restore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15715170/pragma-warning-disable-restore)

Comment: I'd recommend using https://www.nuget.org/packages/stylecop.analyzers/ instead.

Comment: @mjwills Thanks for suggestion but this package is even worse, I need to create two files `stylecop.json` to configure rules and if I want to disable some rules I need to create another one `GlobalSuppressions.cs` and both need to be linked to each project......